# Listview within a Pivot cannot be populated

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have created the following XAML view:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Phone.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PhoneMetar"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Pivot Title="Pivot Title">
        <PivotItem Header="first option">
                <Grid>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="second option">
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="settings">
            <Grid>
                <ListView x:Name="LVSettings" ItemsSource="{Binding SettingsDict}">
                    </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And in the code behind, when trying to create my 'LVSettings' listview, i cannot access it. I am trying to populate it with

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SettingsDict { get; set; }

public static void CreateSettingsList()
{
  SettingsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  SettingsDict.Add("auto download", (Settings.DownloadTimer == true) ? "enabled" : "disabled");
  SettingsDict.Add("download timer", Settings.DownloadInterval.ToString() + " minutes");

            ListView LVSettings = new ListView();
            LVSettings.ItemsSource = SettingsDict;
            LVSettings.SelectionChanged += LVSettings_SelectionChanged;
}
```

I have tried some examples and even when creating a new XAML page without pivots i can make this ListView work, so there must be something wrong here that i cannot identify.

Would you be so kind to point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My Apologies. I just solved the problem, i cannot have my method as static. Although i posted the method as static here, when i tested it in a new page i didn't put it static don't know why, so that's why it worked.

Thank you.